# Как установить аватарку для пользователя в GitLab через API?

Tags: gitlab

Как установить аватарку для пользователя в GitLab через API?

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с версии 9.4 в API добавлен параметр для аватара пользователя.

Из [документации](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#user-modification):

> avatar (optional) - Image file for user's avatar

С помощью CURL картинку можно загрузить через опцию form:

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: %TOKEN%" --form "avatar=@%PATH_TO_FILE%" https://%GITLAB_URL%/avi/v4/users/%USER_ID%
```

Comment: я делаю вот так: curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: R9kYERk23yU8Vzqb2gz1" https://git.example.com/api/v4/users/420?avatar="D:\avatar.png" , но не добавляется аватарка, а если указать другие параметры, например skype, то все корректно добавляется, может как то иначе нужно запрос делать?

Comment: @МингиянДорджиев попробуйте отправить картинку через form. Добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: все равно почему то не срабатывает, делаю так: curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:%2yz7skfF" --form "avatar=/avatar.png" https://git.example/api/v4/users/420, и вот это получаю в ответ: {"error":"email, password, name, username, skype, linkedin, twitter, website_url, organization, projects_limit, extern_uid, provider, bio, location, admin, can_create_group, confirm, external are missing, at least one parameter must be provided"}, пробовал на питоне через python-gitlab, но там то же самое, другие параметру могу добавить а аватарку никак

Comment: @МингиянДорджиев `...at least one parameter must be provided` попробуйте указать один из параметров. Например, добавьте в URL `?username=%USERNAME%`